# Github Repository not publishing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have fully taken every step to publish my repository but the url says"File not found

The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages.

GitHub Status — @githubstatus".

Here is my repository:https://github.com/Rathinadev/videoplayer.
Please check and tell what i can do.

i need to publish the web and wanna know whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your current root project directory is like this:

```
videplayer
|-- .vscode
|-- node_modules
|-- videoplayer
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
```

The nested videoplayer directory has to be the root folder. Move all the files and folders from **/videoplayer/videoplayer** to **/videoplayer**.

The modified folder structure should look like this:

```
videplayer
|-- .vscode
|-- node_modules
|-- public
|-- src
|-- .gitignore
|-- README.md
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
```